# Are there some APIs in GeoTools for the conversion from raster data to vector data?

Tags: geotools

I am new to GeoTools and need to convert raster data to vector data. I want to convert my raster data to features such as point, line, and polygon. I think I've found some for conversions such as 'PolygonExtractionProcess' and 'RasterExtractValuesToPointsOperation' but I'm not sure. I haven't found proper APIs for conversions to line features. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use `PolygonExtractionProcess` for this sort of conversion since even a single "line" of pixels defines a Polygon as pixels have height and width. You would need to look at further post processing of your vector output to convert thin polygons in to lines and short thin polygons in to points.

You may find these [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skeleton) on [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) helpful.